# Selecting index of tabBarController and passing data

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I want to select the UIViewController at index 0 of my tabbarcontroller while passing data to it. It seems I am accessing the UINavigationController instead. Anyone know why this occurs?

```
SearchViewController *search = (SearchViewController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[search initWithText:@"This is a test"];

[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] pushViewController:search animated:NO];
```

// Also receive the error using this:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = search;
```

Error:

```
-[UINavigationController initWithText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: Why in the world are you re-initializing an object which is already initialized?

Comment: You're right, I should not do that. I think I am trying anything out of desperation. I tried just setting the selected controller to my search view. The same error occurs regardless. Thank you for pointing out such a ridiculous mistake, made me think again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, now I feel silly. This worked.

```
UINavigationController *navController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
SearchViewController *search = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[search initWithText:@"This is a test"];
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = navController;
```